# Laravel/CSS - CSS only applying for views in one folder

Tags: css, laravel

My CSS doesn't apply for my userdetails page, but applies for every other page. This is my header which includes the CSS files as well as some bootstraps. My CSS file is in `\laravel-master\public\css`.

```
<head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

I've looked online and a lot of answers suggest adding a "/" before. I've tried adding this to make `<link type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`, but all this does is remove all CSS.

Comment: Use asset() to link your stylesheets, like so: `{{ asset('css/style.css') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you must use [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset) Laravel helper.

```
<link type="text/css" href="{{ asset(/css/style.css) }}" rel="stylesheet">
```